# How to bring taste back when too much creme fraiche is added

Tags: flavor, creme-fraiche

Occasionally it happens that I add to much creme fraiche to a pasta sauce. Recently this happened with a pasta that contained aubergine, courgette, white mushroom, onion, chicken and some pepper and salt. I added the creme fraiche in the last stage.

This made the dish creamy, but also neutralised the flavour of the ingredients.

Is there a way to to partially reverse this neutralisation?

Comment: In my experience, adding cream is what you do when you make a dish that isn't very tasty. The cream neutralizes some of the flavour, and makes the sauce sweeter and fattier, and thus tastier. If a dish is good, simply don't bother with the cream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a squeeze of lemon cuts the creamyness.

Comment: Yes, but it might make a balance problem towards the sour, caused by the creme fraiche, worse. You might need to add some sugar...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the dish and how amenable it is at the stage you make the mistake. Short of redoubling certain ingredients, in most cases, you can't reverse the error.